# How to pass arguments to deployment script?

Tags: python, linux, bash, deployment, ssh

I currently have a structure for deployment which look like this:

1. On the target machine I have a /versions/ directory with the built versions:

```
    /versions/1.0/
    /versions/2.0/
    etc
```

2. To deploy version 2, I run the following command:

```
    ssh host /versions/2.0/deploy.sh var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
```

The problem is that it's very unflexible passing many variables like that. I would like to do something like:

```
    ssh host /versions/2.0/deploy.py config.json
```

or something like

```
   ssh host /version/2.0/deploy.py "{var1: '', var2: '', var3: '', var4: '', var5: ''}"
```

The first solution requires me to first come up with a temporary file name, then copy the config file to the host machine, then execute the deploy script, and then remove the config file.

The second solution I'm not sure about if it's really safe to pass json on the command line.

Any ideas on how I can pass a configuration object/file to my deployment script?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly pass JSON on the command line, but your example is not valid JSON. Note that JSON requires your keys to be quoted with double quotes and the values cannot be single quoted but must be double quoted as well. You'll also want to put single quotes around the entire JSON blob so that you can avoid any shell interaction with the JSON data itself.

Another option would be to use environment variables instead of JSON. Although, this can get ugly if you are passing them via SSH; however, you can use the `env` command to help with this:

```
ssh host env VAR1=value1 VAR2=value2 VAR3=value3 /version/2.0/deploy.py
```

Inside the python script you can access the environment variables via the `os.environ` dictionary.